# C++ is easy once you know PHP

Tags: programming-languages, php, c++

I was at work last week and one of our "lead developers" (who said he has programmed C++ before, but I don't believe him) was talking about C++ and how our team of developers who only know PHP would not have a hard time at all learning C++.

My first reaction was pure shock and then I laughed at his comment. He gave me a bad look and i asked if he was serious. Me personally I program a lot of C and C++ for mostly school projects and coding competitions. I don't think it's at all like PHP. I asked him why they were the same and he could not give me an answer (he doesn't know C++ at all I was thinking). Then I said "OK, yeah they both use curly braces and have conditional statements. But C++ you have to worry about memory management and all the easy to use built in functions in PHP, for example the array functions, are non-existent in C++. You actually have to know the algorithms behind them.". There are some great C++ libraries (STL, Boost) that will make your life easier but C++ is like PHP, come on!

If you already know one language it will make it a little easier to learn another because you will already be good at boolean login (if this then that) or looping but there is just so much more to C++ than PHP. Like you have to compile the language and actually have to define what type of variable you are using and returning from functions.

What do you think?

EDIT: Actually what he said was "C++ is not much different than PHP"

Comment: C++ is easy once you know assembler.

Comment: I think, it's bullshit. Engaging in an argument with someone who is convinced of the opposite is futile. Maybe going with hiphop would be a nice compromise to avoid pointless yelling: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358

Comment: @spoulson: Is that so? Then what in assembler prepares you for the shock of template-meta programming?

Comment: @sbi Try self-modifying code

Comment: @spoulson: I found that much easier to grasp than TMP.

Comment: I think pretty much the opposite is true -- PHP is easy after learning C++ or C, mostly because the syntax is similar and basic library functions at least look familiar.

Comment: I saw this topic title and at first I was like this: O.O  Then I was like this: -.-

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say "X is not much different than Y" for any programming languages X and Y. Don't believe me? Just ask Messrs. Turing and Church.

Comment: @Jon Purdy you are incorrect, you are only considering Turing-complete programming languages.

Comment: @mathepic: Eh, I don't care. Name a non-Turing-complete language that's widely used and still considered a programming language.

Comment: @Jon Purdy - Jon Skeet's Hello Language from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes

Comment: @mathepic: And this is why I really wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: @Jon Purdy I updated your attempt to downvote my comment, which is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 25):

As someone who went from PHP to C++ (though only limited C++) when I started writing C++, I often thought "Wow, this is a lot like PHP". When you consider that PHP itself is written in C, and whenever the developers faced a design decision they couldn't resolve internally, the final answer almost always ended up being "Do it like C++" it's really not that absurd a statement.

Your response about Memory Management and Array Sorting/whatever is a non-starter. That's not a PHP/C++ answer, that's a C++ with zero libraries versus just about every other popular language in existence answer. It feels to me like you're asking this question so that you can get people to agree with you -- that people who write C++ are *so much better* than people who write PHP.

Personally, I think that's a foolish point of view which will lead to nothing but poor decisions on your part.

Comment: PHP is written mostly in C, IIRC.

Comment: @George Edison: You're correct, my mistake. I'll update my post to reflect that.

Comment: How does the fact that PHP is written in C conclude that they have ANYTHING in common?

Comment: @KarimA. How does the fact that the original C++ compiler was written a bit in C?

Comment: .. have anything to do with the relationship between C++ and C?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, if I'll write a LISP interpreter in C, will that mean that these to languages will have more in common?

Comment: @KarimA. exactly. Thats what I was getting at.

Comment: @ColeJohnson your question was answered in the original answer.

Comment: _"When you consider that PHP itself is written in C"_ ...then what? Most code is either written in C or compiled/interpreted by something written in C while running on something written in C. So? Does that mean that all code has some magical relationship with C? This is a bullshit argument. Oh, yeah, and it's true: writing your own sort algorithm in C++ today is stupid. But thinking that, coming from PHP, you could jump right into C++ and produce anything but horrible code is just as stupid. (FWIW, I have taught C++ to Java developers for several years. The code they produce at first is evil.)

Answer (score 19):

Sounds like one "team lead" guy (also a PHP dev like yours) who told me that C++ "sucks, take templates for example". Much as I try not to, lines like those always flip the infamous bozo bit with me.

Your friend has a HUGE problem here, namely he is so overconfident that ***he does*** ***not know how much he does not know***.

Saying that learning C++ is easy once you know PHP is like saying that once you can drive a *Segway*, it would be quite easy to learn operating an Airbus A-380, because, 'you know, they both have some wheels to stand on and are controlled by advanced embedded circuit boards.

Comment: You nailed it. "he does not know how much he does not know." This a bug for most C++ beginners.

Comment: Eh, i don't know how much i agree with that. I basically know about 95% of the quirks of PHP. I was able to learn Java and Python in a single day. I jumped right in on a few C++ opensource projects and nailed some pull requests with ease, and bug free code. The thing that overwhelmed me was pointers, templates, and the seemingly endless variable types. I am able to do very simple things in C++. To master it, i can see myself spending about 3x the amount of time(6 months) it took me to master PHP.The reason i could jump write in to C++ was because of the similarity in syntax

Comment: @r3wt Well you basically just reinforced my arguments. Like I said, many C++ beginners have no idea how much they don't know. Jumping on the bandwagon and producing some code in a week is not so much of an issue for most of at least somewhat competent programmers. We all try out a new language once in a while. And we can jump on it rather quickly because a lot of imperative languages bear many syntax similarities. However saying that you could become a master in C++ in 6 months, no offense, shows that you too don't know how much you much you don't know.

Comment: @Jas the estimate was **18 months** `3 * 6 = 18`

Comment: @r3wt - Sorry, it sounded as if it took you in total 2 months to learn PHP, which I wouldn't be surprised of as PHP is such a joke of a language. Anyway, let's get it rolling and let me know how you fare with C++ mastery in 18 months from now :)

Comment: @Jas Anyone can claim mastery of a language, but when you've mastered the art of abstracting away its flaws i would say that counts as "Mastery".

Answer (score 5):

There is programming as a skill independent of any language, and then there is knowledge of a specific language's constructs, libraries, and conventions.  You can be great at the former and suck at the latter (for a specific language) or vice versa.

Without knowing anything about your team, we can't say whether they'd be good at C++.  And there are various ways to write C++ too, as some people get themselves stuck 20 years ago without the stdlib, boost, other libraries, or even without compiler features everyone else takes for granted.

However, there are a lot of problems with C++, and as someone that both loves and hates it, yet still has it for the highest count on SO, I'll be the first to admit it really sucks at times.  Then again, the more you know about a language, the more you find out how it sucks.  If there's any tool where you consider yourself an expert, yet you can't name at least 10 ways it's broken, inadequate, or you just hate it... :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you called out a bluffer (I refer to the fact that he couldn't back up his statement) :). This is no bad thing as long as it's done politely, respectfully and with technical merit.

Comment: yeah, at first i thought he was making a joke, which is why i laughed...

Answer (score 2):

I think your "lead developer" should consider another line of work. Seriously, though, this usenet post I saw a year ago about C++ says it all:

> I don't know about you, but there's something really scary to me about a
> language where copying state from one object to another is this
> complicated.  By now, I suspect at least a dozen or two programmers have
> contributed something new to this discussion. If it takes this many
> programmers to write a simple assignment operator, think how complicated
> writing code that actually does something meaningful must be!

Comment: I have no idea why people complicate copying in C++: `T& operator=(T other) { swap(*this, other); return *this; } friend void swap(T &a, T &b) { using std::swap; swap(a.each_member, b.each_member); }`

Comment: @Roger: What's in the swap function? Does it need to be a separate function? If so, why?

Comment: @Larry: It swaps each member that needs swapped.  The simplest and shortest way to write it is exactly as I have above; some people like to confuse the issue with a swap method rather than free function, but then add a free function and maybe specialize std::swap, but then you can't partially specialize it and cannot overload... — all over-complication: the copy-and-swap idiom has been widespread for at least 7 years now, there's no excuse for not using it in C++.

Comment: @Roger: Thanks for the answer. I was just curious about the details. I haven't done anything in C++ for years. We use C# at work, at home I use either Lisp or Haskell depending on the task.

Comment: @Larry: Well, it's even more complicated in Haskell to "copy" state: try explaining zip-lists or finger-trees to the average programmer. :)

Comment: @Roger: I'm not going to try explaining *anything* in Haskell to the average programmer, especially not monads, which is what I would normally use for managing state.

Comment: And I avoided that bucket (not can) of worms for a reason. :)

Comment: in our company bad programmers get promoted to lead positions because the business guys think they wont be programming anymore. Good programmers always end up quiting because of this and they can't figure out why they are all leaving. Stupid office politics...

Comment: @gprime: Read [ *The Peter Principle* ](http://www.amazon.com/Peter-Principle-Laurence-J/dp/1568491611); IIRC, he studied one company that had ~50 vice presidents for exactly that reason.

Comment: @Larry: C++ suffers from/revels in the same kind of problems Lisp has had. Its users rarely just want the simplest answer to deal with today's problem. Rather, they're basically developing a philosophy of programming that deals with entire classes of problems. For years Lisp had similar debates: Should cons cons its arguments? (and/or should const evaluate its arguments?), lexical vs. dynamic scoping, is it good to treat `nil` as equivalent to `false`?, etc. All of these (and more) have been debated at *tremendous* length --by comparison, debates over C++ are fairly trivial.

Comment: @Jerry: That's an interesting bit of history, and the same sort of thing is currently happening in the Haskell community. I suppose this happens with any language that has a community above the level of "I don't care, I just want my program to work."

Comment: @Larry: Oh, I see you've written PHP before...

Comment: @Roger: I looked at PHP very briefly about 9 years ago, but I don't do any web development at home, so I never seriously used it. The "I don't care" comment was really about working with VB6.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a first thought, he could be referring to the syntactical styles. Yes there are a few differences in how certain things like string concatenation and arrays work but they are easily enough learned. Then there are pointers and things of that nature but once again, if you have solid knowledge of basic CS concepts then it shouldn't be a problem. I don't think that the statement is that far out of the ballpark, but I am by no means saying that it would be easy. C++ is a tough language to tackle.

Answer (score 1):

Why is everyone always griping about memory management in php? Just because the language attempts to do garbage collection for you, doesn't mean that it's adequate, and you can forget about it. The memory you use in PHP does matter. And that's why you use functions like memory_get_usage(). Just because PHP is very forgiving and allows some awful practices to compile, doesn't mean that you should use awful practices in writing code. The biggest difference I see between php and C++ syntactically is that PHP has less brutally ugly syntax. If you compare PHP and C++ in the scenarios you would use PHP, they're very similar. You just need to remember to top load your libraries in C++, which I find annoying. C++ does appeal to my inner need to control every detail of execution, though.